# Concentration of gas phase in Nernst equation

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

What if one or both electrodes are in gas phase? Use PV=nRT? Also the definition of hydrogen electrode gets a little sketchy if we use PV=nRT to write it's concentration, the electrode potential doesn't come out 0 that way.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't come out 0? The Hydrogen electrode potential is assigned an arbitrary zero in order to have a reference point. It doesn't have a zero value under any circumstances. In order to answer your question anyway, we use pressure values as proxies for the activity of gases, not concentration.

Comment: So we use pressure values instead of concentration even in cases where ionic and gas phase both are present?

Comment: That is correct. Pressure for gaseous reactants and concentrations for dissolved ones.